# Writing sql command command into a file

Tags: mysql, sql

Below is the Mysql command which i used to write the specific table columns into a file called result.txt

```
Select EMAILID,ZUID from MailBox INTO OUTFILE 'result.txt';
```

After executing the command i get the output

```
Query OK, 8 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

But when i search for the file , i find that it hasn't been created. So please clarify whether this command actually writes the command into the file?? If not, what is the correct command to write sql command's result into an output file??. Sorry in case the question sounds noobish.

Comment: generally it goes into the system temp directory. e.g. `/tmp/result.txt`. perhaps it'd be c:\windows\temp\result.txt or c:\users\yourusername\appdata\local\temp, etc... many options

Comment: @Marc: Thanks..am using linux and am able to create the file in the /tmp/ directory but not able to create under home directory!!

Comment: remember that the mysql server is the one creating the file, and it will not have access rights to your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

As the [documentation states](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html), it does output the results to a file. You are most likely not looking for the file in the right place. Try adding an absolute path instead of a relative one.

You should also take into account that the owner of the file is the `mysql` user (at least in linux).

Comment: ERROR 1 (HY000): I am running on ubuntu..Can't create/write to file '/etc/mysql/results.txt' (Errcode: 13).. this is the error i get when i specify the absolute path.

Comment: It is not a good idea to output query results into the system configuration :) Create a folder in your home, eg: `/home/aarish/test/` then give it additional privs (eg: `chmod 777 /home/aarish/test`) and then output to the file `/home/aarish/test/results.txt`. That should work. Using `/tmp` is another option.

Comment: Creating the file in the /tmp folder works..Thank you:).. but while trying to write to a file ,by changing its directory's access permissions in the way u stated ,gives me the same error "ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/home/aarish/test/results.txt' (Errcode: 13)":(

Comment: Remember these files are created as if the `mysql` user is doing it, so you must be able to access this as another user. Many Linux distributions wall-off home directories, so you'll have to `chmod +rx ~aarish`

Comment: @tadman: As you suggested, i tried 'chmod +rx ~/aarish/temp'and tried writing to a file in the directory but it gives me the error ,"Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/ /home/aarish/temp/results.txt' (Errcode: 2)".. One thing which i didn't understand is why is it showing me this path '/var/lib/mysql/ ' when i am working in the home directory and trying to create the file in the specified path??.. sry in case the question is very fundamental, i am a newbie to mysql.

Comment: Why is there a space in the middle of that?